# Change the owner of a locked folder in Windows 8 through command line

Tags: windows, excel, vba

I am currently locking a folder for 'everyone' for no access. I am doing it through excel VBA code and command line. 
So, when the excel sheet is open at my end, I am the owner for it. But, when the excel sheet is copied to other path and is opened by other user, I need to make that new user, the owner for changing permissions.
As the folder is locked, command line code is not able to change the owner.
I have tries
'sudo chown'
and 
'takeown'
commands.. but no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link on "How to Take Full Ownership of Files & Folders in Windows 8"
You can check it :
http://www.thewindowsclub.com/take-ownership-windows-8